# Исключить подгруппу из многострочной группы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В многострочном тексте нужно захватить родительские группы вместе с подгруппой. Родительские группы начинаются с U. Как из подгрупп исключить мусор SC?

Написал выражение

```
^U\d(\n\d+(?:\nSC)?)+
```

но оно захватывает SC.

Пример текста:

```
U1
176
SC
U2
157
SC
157
SC
159
SC
U3
179
254
```

Должны получиться группы:

```
U1
176

U2
157
157
159

U3
179
254
```

Comment: С помощью регулярных выражений - никак. Сначала найдите совпадения, а потом удалите `SC`, что-то вроде `result = result.Replace("\nSC", "")`. На каком языке пишете код?

Comment: На 1С. Думал о таком способе, но хотелось бы сделать красиво. Спасибо.